# RxJava: Consume result of Observable on another thread

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I need to perform some work on background thread and then deliver result on main thread. I do the following:

```
Observable.just(new Object()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(Object s) {

                try {
                    doSomething()
                    Observable.just(new Object())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNext(Object o) {
                                    completion.deliverResult()
                                    onComplete();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete() {

                                }
                            });
                } catch (DriverException e) {
                    badThingsHappened()
                    onError(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
```

But I don't like this code, it seems complex and many things are not used.

Is there a way to do it more elegant?

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be converted to something similar to this one:

```
    Observable
            .create(emitter -> {
                Result result;
                try {
                    result = doSomething();
                } catch (Exception error) {
                    emitter.onError(error);
                    return;
                } finally {
                    if (result == null) {
                        emitter.onError(new IllegalStateException("Result cannot be null"));
                        return;
                    }
                }
                emitter.onNext(result);
                emitter.onComplete();
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> completion.deliverResult(result),
                    throwable -> badThingsHappened(throwable));
```

But with this approach you are mixing traditional callbacks with reactive programming: `completion.deliverResult()` is a standard callback. Instead of doing that, return the observable stream itself and let the interested client to observe the stream itself.

Comment: what object type is emmiter inside create ? I see available constructor for ObservableEmitter but it requires to implement 8 methods.

Comment: It's `ObservableOnSubscribe`. See [`Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

you can do what you want in few lines of codes.

In this snippet I'm creating a Observable object from a Callable. The computation will be done on IO thread, but the result (or error eventually) will be observed on Android main thread

```
void execute() {
    // here you get your observable (api, db, other repositories). I'll create a simple String observable
    Observable<String> observable = Observable.fromCallable(
            () -> "This method will be executed on IO Thread"
    );

    // here you create your observer. I'll observe a string, so I need a Observer<String> obj
    Observer<String> stringObserver = new StringObserver();

    //now the observable will do his job on IO thread, but the result is emitted on mainThread
    observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(stringObserver);
}

class StringObserver extends DisposableObserver<String> {
    @Override
    public void onNext(String s) {
        //will be executed on main thread
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

        //will be executed on main thread
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {

        //will be executed on main thread
    }
}
```